# How to disable rtf field in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, fields

I have a requirement where one  sf rtf field has to be disabled  based on some condition. I am not finding any solution for disabling rtf. Anybody worked on this or any work arounf for this?

Comment: Is the condition based on the value of another field? or...?

Comment: yes it is based on some other field

Answer (score 2):

Much depends on what you mean by disabled.  The examples below assume your object instance is `MyObj__c`, the RT field is `My_RTF__c` and the field that determines if the RT field should be displayed is `Other__c`.

If you don't want the RT field to be displayed based on the value of another field, you can use conditional rendering:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!MyObj__c.My_RTF__c}" rendered="{!MyObj__c.Other__c=='showRTF'}" />
```

If you want the input to remain, but not be a rich text variety, you could keep the about line of markup to render the RT, but if the value of `Other__c` is not `showRTF`, then render a regular text area backed by the field

```
<apex:inputTextArea value="{!MyObj__c.My_RTF__c}" rendered="{!MyObj__c.Other__c!='showRTF'}" />
```

If you need to react to the changing of the `Other__c` field elsewhere in the page, I'd look at adding an `<apex:actionSupport />` element to the `Other__c` input, which can rerender the part(s) of the page that contain the conditionally rendered items.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_using_rich_text_area.htm&language=en_US

Check the link which may help you